# TENS unit design

Tags: amplifier, boost

I've been working on a circuit to amplify TENS signals.

The initial signal is coming from a phone which is then amplified to about 31 Vrms(~20 peak to peak) and then connected to the human body through electrodes. Since I'm using a general-purpose op-amp (LM741) for it, the output is limited to 40mA.

I can see the output on the scope which is 31 Vrms, and when I connect a 1k ohm resistor it can still maintain the voltage.

When I connect it to myself through the electrodes (jumpers for now,) I can't feel the signal.

The circuit that I'm using is below.

It's a simple DC-DC boost circuit, it converts two 9 volt batteries to -20 +20. The rest is just a non-inverting op-amp configuration set to provide ~15 gain. I know the design is incomplete right now but for the time being I just want to be able to feel the signal.

What should I do to feel the signal? If I were to boost the signal even more, would I need a stronger amplifier?

I was thinking OPA454. How much more voltage do I need to be able to feel it,or is it something entirely different that I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Don't attach a human to a 31 Vrms source that you've designed yourself. Full stop. That's dangerous, your question and your circuit tell us that you don't have the necessary background to make it safe, and I'll allow myself to claim that the therapeutic efficacy of shocking yourself with this kind of electronics is to be heavily dubious.$$\,$$You've built an unregulated boost converter – that's a terrible choice. The NE555 is a terrible choice.

Comment: I'd suggest you want more than 31V - more like 100V. But things start to get a bit dangerous, so I'd suggest you do a lot of research and understand the safety issues involved. I don't know what use the op-amp is, from what little I know of TENS machines, they pulse a high voltage, low current so you need a boost converter and some means of pulsing that, say a microcontroller. By low current, I'd be guessing at less than 1mA - again you want to fully understand the safety requirements and how to design fail-safe electronics lest you electrocute yourself - no kidding.

Comment: The LM741 op-amp might have been described as general purpose just before man first landed on the moon but today, unfortunately, it's described in less than favourable terms such as a [crock-of....](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=crock%20of%20shit)

Comment: Exactly, as I said the circuit is incomplete, there are no fail-safes at all. But I was wondering why I wasn't feeling anything, All the commercial designs claim a max current of 40mA and 50V so I was confused. The NE555 is just a placeholder, initially, the boost converter had feedback but I had to scratch that design for the sake of simplicity. And yup, I'm aware of the dangers of this project. I do wish I didn't have to work on it but it is how it is.

Comment: TENS uses pulses at much lower rates than you are using.  I'm not sure you can generate the required pulses with a normal signal generator program on a phone.  TENS pulses are square waves.  The devices vary the pulse rate and the pulse width to change intensity.  The same pulse rate with a wider pulse width is stronger than a narrower pulse width.  Audio frequencies are usually too fast for muscles to react to.  100 pulses per second is close to the top end of reaction speed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the ancient and venerable 741 has a maximum current output of 25 mA.

Comment: 50V at 40 mA is only possible if your skin has a resistance around 1kohm.  Typical people have skin resistance of at least some tens of kiloohms.  I doubt you will get 50V and 40 milliamperes at the same time out of a TENS unit.  Both values are likely maximums that never occur together.

Comment: What you feel is heavily dependent on electrodes. Large area and saline gel are needed

Comment: So I'm looking at a frequency of about below 100Hz and a voltage of way more than 31v?. And of course proper electrodes.

Comment: The voltage and current are probably OK - at least somewhat like what a TENS unit delivers.  The frequency and signal shape are most likely the problem.

Comment: @Kartman Even 9V can be felt with the proper electrodes, no need to go up to the dangerous voltages of 100V

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to buy an actual FDA-approved TENS unit on a secondary market (Craigslist, eBay, what have you), then attach it to a *body simulator* (a suitable RC circuit), and measure the voltages and currents involved. Then make sure that whatever you come up with is in the same ballpark.

Comment: What's wrong with just attaching electrodes to your leg and doing the measurements? (They are only about 30 USD on Amazon.) Finding specs for a body simulator might pose a significant barrier to a bioenginerically unsophisticated experimenter.